# Refreshing dataGridView items on adding or deleting entry in database?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

i am adding , deleting and updating data to database in Winforms. i have gridview on all add,delete and update forms.
After deleting records on clicking "delete" button  deleted record should removed instantly from dataGridView.

////Please note that DATABIND is giving error i.e. using or assembly reference missing.

Code Behind:

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtIDD.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill ID no. of record to Delete", "Important Message");

        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                Cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                Cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM AddressBook WHERE ID="+txtIDD.Text;
                Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Cmd.Connection.Close();
                conn.Close();
                dataGridView3.Update();
                MessageBox.Show("Delete Succesfull");
            }
            catch (System.Exception err)
            {
                  dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
                  dataGridView3.DataBind();
                  dataGridView3.Update();

                this.label27.Visible = true;
                this.label27.Text = err.Message.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: Just my personal opinion, but if the grid contains the data that should be deleted, I'd reverse the logic: user enters text, you search the relevant record(s) in your grid, execute the delete in the db, and after that, remove the records from the gird directly or from the underlying bound datasource. (added advantage is that you could also have a delete action directly on selected rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the grid again to fetch values form database after add, update and delete etc.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (txtIDD.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill ID no. of record to Delete", "Important Message");

    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            Cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            Cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM AddressBook WHERE ID="+txtIDD.Text;
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Cmd.Connection.Close();
            conn.Close();                

            **//Call a method that binds the grid or get DataTable from database and bind it like this**
             dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;               
            dataGridView3.Update();

            MessageBox.Show("Delete Succesfull");
        }
        catch (System.Exception err)
        {
            this.label27.Visible = true;
            this.label27.Text = err.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey bro i m making windows application . Databind() is not working there :( it gives error that using or assembly reference missing

Comment: Remove DataBind() assigning datasource is enough but get the latest data before assigning to datasource

Comment: i have used the function to get the updated data :)))) its working fine

Comment: Call the method after delete to get latest changes in grid

Answer (score -2):

Create a function whereby you can reload the grid

```
private method ReloadGrid()
{
   // first load your datatable/dt then set it as the datasource of your grid
   dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
   dataGridView3.DataBind();

}
```